# jQuery height always returns 0

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

I stuck in a simple jQuery height of an element. I want to get the element's actual height. But I always gets 0.

I tried the following code.

```
jQuery('.inclusions2').height(); 
jQuery('#inclusions2').outerHeight();
jQuery('#inclusions2').prop('scrollHeight');
jQuery('#inclusions2').innerHeight();
```

All codes always return 0.

Here is the live code URL where I am checking. [Link](http://dev.highplaces.co.uk/demo_html/tour_details.html)

**Edit 1**

Here is the code sample.

```
<div class="tab" id="inclusions2">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="tab_contents">
            <div class="section-title text-center">
                <div class="title-border">
                    <h1><span>Inclusions</span></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="tab_para"><strong>The above prices are based on below Inclusions with</strong> ONE FOC in a Single room.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I check it on a test page the code works and returns actual height but on the site it always returns 0.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Also be sure to [search thoroughly](/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+height+always+returns+0) before posting, which usually finds you your answer right away, but if not say what you looked at from the search, and be clear about having tried those previous answers and what about them didn't work. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: `$('.inclusions2')` is targeting `class="inclusions2"`, but you're only using `id="inclusions2"`, which is (correctly) targeted via `$('#inclusions2')`. Fix this and see if you have more luck.

Comment: @TimLewis I tried both, but no luck

Comment: I figured there was more to it, but `$(".inclusions2")` won't return any elements, so that should explain why it returns 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `#inclusions2` element only contains one floated element/child (`col-md-12`) Since floated content doesn't count/isn't calculated for height per default, you get zero height (which can also be seen when using the browser tools on that element).

However, if you add `overflow: visible;` to the CSS rule for `#inclusions2`, this behaviour changes and your jQuery code (using `outerHeight()`) will work as expected.